# When clicking on submit button, the onClick() method is not getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new to react, I am strugging in troubleshooting the error or mistake I am making. When I click on submit button after filling the data the page neither refreshes nor it shows any success message. Can anyone plz help me with this
This is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";

import AuthService from "./services/auth.service";

import Login from "./components/login.component";
import Register from "./components/register.component";
import Home from "./components/home.component";
import Profile from "./components/profile.component";
import BoardUser from "./components/board-user.component";
import BoardAdmin from "./components/board-admin.component";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      showAdminBoard: false,
      currentUser: undefined
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();

    if (user) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: user,
        showAdminBoard: user.roles.includes("ROLE_ADMIN")
      });
    }
  }

  logOut() {
    AuthService.logout();
  }

  render() {
    const { currentUser, showAdminBoard } = this.state;

    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <Link to={"/"} className="navbar-brand">
              Flight Reservation System
            </Link>
            <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/home"} className="nav-link">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>

              {showAdminBoard && (
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/admin"} className="nav-link">
                    Admin 
                  </Link>
                </li>
              )}

              {currentUser && (
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/user"} className="nav-link">
                    User
                  </Link>
                </li>
              )}
            </div>

            {currentUser ? (
              <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/profile"} className="nav-link">
                    {currentUser.username}
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a href="/login" className="nav-link" onClick={this.logOut}>
                    LogOut
                  </a>
                </li>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                    Login
                  </Link>
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/register"} className="nav-link">
                    Sign Up
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </div>
            )}
          </nav>

          <div className="container mt-3">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={["/", "/home"]} component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
              <Route exact strict path="/user" component={BoardUser} />
              <Route exact strict path="/admin" component={BoardAdmin} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my board-admin.component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../Navbar.css";
import AddComponent from "./add-component";
import DeleteComponent from "./delete-component";
import UpdateComponent from "./update-component";
import UserService from "../services/user.service";

export default class BoardAdmin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      content: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    UserService.getAdminBoard().then(
      response => {
        this.setState({
          content: response.data
        });
      },
      error => {
        this.setState({
          content:
            (error.response &&
              error.response.data &&
              error.response.data.message) ||
            error.message ||
            error.toString()
        });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
      <div className="navbars">
            <ul>
                <li>
                <Link className="link" to={"/add"} >
                  Add
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link className="link" to={"/update"} >
                  Update
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link className="link" to={"/delete"}>
                  Delete
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div >
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/add" component={AddComponent} />
              <Route exact path="/update" component={UpdateComponent} />
              <Route path="/delete" component={DeleteComponent} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my add-component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FlightsService from "../services/flights.service";

export default class AddComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeName = this.onChangeName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeFrom = this.onChangeFrom.bind(this);
    this.onChangeTo = this.onChangeTo.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
    this.onChangeFare = this.onChangeFare.bind(this);
    this.saveFlight = this.saveFlight.bind(this);
    this.newFlight = this.newFlight.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      id: null,
      name: "",
      from: "",
      to: "",
      date: "",
      fare: "",
      submitted: false
    };
  }

  onChangeName(e) {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangeFrom(e) {
    this.setState({
      from: e.target.value
    });
  }
  onChangeTo(e) {
    this.setState({
      to: e.target.value
    });
  }
  onChangeDate(e) {
    this.setState({
      date: e.target.value
    });
  }
  onChangeFare(e) {
    this.setState({
      fare: e.target.value
    });
  }

  saveFlight() {
    var data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      from: this.state.from,
      to:this.state.to,
      date:this.state.date,
      fare:this.state.fare
    };

    FlightsService.create(data)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          id: response.data.id,
          name: response.data.name,
          from: response.data.from,
          to: response.data.to,
          date:response.data.date,
          fare:response.data.fare,
          submitted: true
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }

  newFlight() {
    this.setState({
      id: null,
      name: "",
      from: "",
      to: "",
      date: "",
      fare:"",
      submitted: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="submit-form">
        {this.state.submitted ? (
          <div>
            <h4>You submitted successfully!</h4>
            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.newFlight}>
              Add
            </button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="title">Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="title"
                required
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.onChangeName}
                name="title"
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="description">From</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="description"
                required
                value={this.state.from}
                onChange={this.onChangeFrom}
                name="description"
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="description">To</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="description"
                required
                value={this.state.to}
                onChange={this.onChangeTo}
                name="description"
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="description">Date</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="description"
                required
                value={this.state.date}
                onChange={this.onChangeDate}
                name="description"
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="description">Fare</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="description"
                required
                value={this.state.fare}
                onChange={this.onChangeFare}
                name="description"
              />
            </div>

            <button onClick={this.saveFlight} className="btn btn-success">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my axios related data:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8002/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

This is my service:

```
import http from "../http-common";

class FlightsService {
  
  create(data) {
    return http.post("/flights", data);
  }

  update(id, data) {
    return http.put(`/flights/${id}`, data);
  }

  delete(id) {
    return http.delete(`/flights/${id}`);
  }
}
export default new FlightsService();
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console (F12) after you click the save/submit button?

Comment: Do either of the console logs in `saveFlight ` output at all?

Comment: There is too much going on here for most potential answerers (including me) to want to sift through it. You should try to do some basic debugging yourself, using the developer tools (including React developer tools) - to answer some basic questions, such as: is the network request being made? Is a response coming back, and is it the one you expect? Is the state being updated in the way you expect? By looking at each part in turn you should be able to narrow down where the problem lies, and then if you are still stuck, reduce the problem to a small example which we can more easily help with.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MattU I have got the solution for the problem, it was CORS problem, troubleshooted it by doing console(F12)

Answer (score -2):

have you tried annon functions ?

```
            <button onClick={this.saveFlight} className="btn btn-success">
```

into

```
            <button onClick={()=>{this.saveFlight()}} className="btn btn-success">
```

you are also binding the function of the click handler to the class of the component. I'm not sure if that is correct (not 100% on react best practices), I haven't dove too deeply into react - but using a master click Handler that handles all click events at the app level has been my strategy when binding functions... that has worked - but I can't guarantee it's not a terrible idea.